# (Swift) Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AVAudioInputNode'

Tags: xcode, conditional-statements, option-type, speech, avaudioengine

I am trying to create a speech to text function and I am getting the error:

`Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AVAudioInputNode'`

```
guard let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode else {
        fatalError("Audio engine has no input node")
    }
```

Comment: I have exactly the opposite problem, in my case the `inputNode` is optional even though the documentation says otherwise.

Comment: How did you achieve that it is not nil? Do you use Swift 4? Which "AV" framework do you link into your project?

Comment: this is straight from Apple's sample code and it doesn't appear to work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`AVAudioEngine`'s `inputNode` property is not an optional. The Audio Engine creates a singleton on demand when inputNode is first accessed. It cannot be nil and because of that the guard does not make sense.

So, just remove the guard and use `audioEngine.inputNode` as it is. It cannot be `nil`.

You still have to make sure that the `inputNode` is connected to something before using it:

> Check the input format of input node (specifically, the hardware
>   format) for a non-zero sample rate and channel count to see if input
>   is enabled.

(from Apple's Documentation)

Comment: What should we do when the frequency or channel count are zero? I have encountered this situation a few times and only device restart fixed it...

Comment: anyone able to fix the problem what @shelll have mentioned?

Comment: Worth noting it actually used to be optional prior to iOS 11.